# JQuery:Google map loads partially

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to integrate GoogleMap in hash page in my project.When I navigate from a page to mappage

googlemap loads partially.When i refresh this hash page it loads successfully.This is the code :

```
function markicons() {

    InitializeMap();
    var ltlng = [];
    ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(-36.847043, 174.761543));
    ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(-37.791174,175.297813));
    ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(-38.679988,176.077843));
    ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(-41.297257,174.759483));

    map.setCenter(ltlng[0]);
    for (var i = 0; i <= ltlng.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: ltlng[i]
        });

        (function (i, marker) {

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                if (!infowindow) {

                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                }

                infowindow.setContent("Message" + i);

                infowindow.open(map, marker);

            });

        })(i, marker);

    }

}

window.onload = markicons;
```

How can I fix this problem?Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.I just called markicons()  inside the window.hashchange function not in the window.load.Here is the code:

```
  $(window).on("hashchange", function () {
    if(window.location.hash=="#contactUI")
    {

   markicons();
    }
});
```